# Does $.getJSON(url.params) correctly format a URL?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm accessing JSON data from OpenWeatherAPI. A correct format for the URL is

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Chicago&APPID=34lkj349gga9s8dug9sd8hg

Where ?q={city}&APPID={API_key}

Suppose I provide the url, the q param, and the APPID param. I use the $.getJSON functionality to retrieve the JSON data. Does $.getJSON know that URLs are formatted with ?, =, and & or do I have to write those in with my own params? Currently all I return is localhost/?

Here is the short program I wrote. It is well commented to explain how I expect it to work.

```
  // Here is how the final url should look:
  // api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Chicago&APPID=33lkr3jlfj39asdflk

var weatherSearch = '';
  // weather-search is my html form id. On submit, send the input
  // (which is city name) to the function getWeather.
$('#weather-search').submit(function(event) {
weatherSearch = $('#weatherQuery').val();
event.preventDefault();
getWeather(weatherSearch);
});

  // getWeather has params q (city name), and APPID (API key).
function getWeather(weatherSearch) {
var params = {
        q: weatherSearch,
        APPID: '33lkr3jlfj39asdflk'
};
  // This is the url that goes before the params.
url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather/';
  // Request data using url and params above.
  // Does $.getJSON format the url properly?
$.getJSON(url. params, function(data) {
  // Pass JSON data to showWeather function.
        showWeather(data.items);
        console.log(data.items);
});
}

function showWeather(weather) {
  // Show JSON data (weather) in html div id="weatherResults"
$('#weatherResults').html(weather);

}
```

This is the html that is referenced by the JavaScript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>weather</title>
<script src="/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="openweather.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="weather-search">
<input type="text" id="weatherQuery"></input>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
</form>

<div id="weatherResults">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try comma "`,`" instad of dot "`.`" :

```
$.getJSON(url, params, function(data) {
  // Pass JSON data to showWeather function.
        showWeather(data.items);
        console.log(data.items);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will automatically encode the URL with ?q=weatherSearch&APPID=33lkr3jlfj39asdflk

Just switch your getJson to

```
$.getJSON(url, params, function(data) {
  // Pass JSON data to showWeather function.
        showWeather(data.items);
        console.log(data.items);
});
```

you had a **period** instead of a **comma** after `url`

See this codepen with a working example
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqwPyQ

Comment: yes but concatenating strings in javascript is not with `.` it's with `+` -> `url. params` is actually `url+params`

Comment: he can't retrieve result as it require POST method.

Comment: The API throwing error `Object {error: "Please use POST request"}` any way to add `POST` method to `$.getJSON`

Comment: Actually @KalpeshSingh I looked at their API, and it is in fact a GET request. If you take a second to look at my codepen, you can see it working fine

Comment: @KalpeshSingh he had a period after url.  There needed to be a comma

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107336/discussion-between-kalpesh-singh-and-nick-delaney).

Comment: I see your codepen outputting to the codepen console. I can't get this working on localhost. Any idea why? Even if I copy and paste your exact codepen.

Comment: Are you getting an error in your console?  It's most likely due to a cross-origin issue

Comment: I'm getting nothing on the console. What is cross-origin?

Comment: When a request is from one domain to another domain. For example localhost to api.openweathermap.org